# WCF Service: File upload ends in Protocol exception: MaxArraylength exceeded

Tags: wcf, iis, file-upload

I'm coding a webservice at the moment and the usage is as followed:

I got a frontend as dll, means I got a library project with a wpf window.
That library shall be called from other programs.
The Backend WCF-service is hosted on an external IIS and the frontend calls the webservice methods via a controller.dll where the wcf service is referenced.

I've read several post here and from google already about the same issue...but I can't get it fixed.

I got a dummy windows forms, which calls the frontend.dll.
That project got that app.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IService" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
            openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00"
            allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
            maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
            messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
            useDefaultWebProxy="true">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647"
              maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
                realm="" />
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://Hidden-ip/TicketReportService.svc"
          binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IService"
          contract="ServiceReference.IService" name="BasicHttpBinding_IService" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

I'm aware, that each program that wants to call my frontend.dll would need to put the binding/endpoint configurations in their own app.config if I proceed like i described here.
Thats just an example though, later I'm doing the binding/endpoint config programaticallly in my controller.dll, so I dont need configuration files...but thats another topic.

If I call my method, that uploads the file via the webservice I got two scenarios:

if file > 16kb and <~30kb I get a protoccol exception, thats telling me that the `"MaxArrayLength" (16384) was exceeded`.

if I'm trying to upload a file with about 60kb I get a protocoll exception as well, but just with the information: "`remoteserver returned unexpected answer.(400) bad request.`

If you look in the app.config, the maxarray length is setted to int32.max value.
Also if I check the binding of the object that calls the method, its telling me that the maxarraylength was taken from the app.config....but I'm still getting the error message.

What did I wrong here?
Thats a client side issue, i'snt it?

In my service web.config on the IIS I got following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <services>
            <service behaviorConfiguration="BackendService.Behavior" name="MyNamespaye.Service">
                <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="MyNamespaye.IService" />
                <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
            </service>
        </services>
        <behaviors>
            <serviceBehaviors>
                <behavior name="BackendService.Behavior">
                    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
                    <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
                </behavior>
            </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
    </system.serviceModel>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="CustomerEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/CustomerModel.csdl|res://*/CustomerModel.ssdl|res://*/CustomerModel.msl;provider=MySql.Data.MySqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;server=hidden-ip;User Id=root;database=fromcloud;password=hidden-pw;Persist Security Info=True&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
        <add name="DocumentEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/DocumentModel.csdl|res://*/DocumentModel.ssdl|res://*/DocumentModel.msl;provider=MySql.Data.MySqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;server=hidden-ip;User Id=root;password=hidden-pw;Persist Security Info=True;database=fromcloud&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

...fixed it myself. Didn't know that it has to be configured on the service side as well!

new web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IService" closeTimeout="00:10:00"
                    openTimeout="00:10:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00"
                    allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                    maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
                    messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
                    useDefaultWebProxy="true">
                    <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647"
                        maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
                    <security mode="None">
                        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
                            realm="" />
                        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
                    </security>
                </binding>
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <services>
            <service behaviorConfiguration="BackendService.Behavior" name="MyNamespace.Service">
              <host>
                  <baseAddresses>
                    <add baseAddress="http://localhost:1111/"/>
                  </baseAddresses>
            </host>
             <endpoint address="http://MyIP/TicketReportService.svc"
                  binding="basicHttpBinding" 
                  bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IService"
                  contract="Mynamespace.BackendService.IService" 
                  name="ticketReport_endpoint" />

            </service>
        </services>
        <behaviors>
            <serviceBehaviors>
                <behavior name="BackendService.Behavior">
                    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
                    <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
                </behavior>
            </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
    </system.serviceModel>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="CustomerEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/CustomerModel.csdl|res://*/CustomerModel.ssdl|res://*/CustomerModel.msl;provider=MySql.Data.MySqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;server=fwefwef;User Id=root;database=fromcloud;password=fwefw;Persist Security Info=True&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
        <add name="DocumentEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/DocumentModel.csdl|res://*/DocumentModel.ssdl|res://*/DocumentModel.msl;provider=MySql.Data.MySqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;server=fwefwef;User Id=root;password=fwef;Persist Security Info=True;database=fromcloud&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

...just did another google search and found a proper exampel of a web.config.
Thanks anyway for anyone that read the OP.